# ILLEGAL token / unterminated string literal in single line string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I know, there are a lot already answered questions regarding the "unterminated string literal" error in Javascript, but I simply cannot find out what's wrong with a certain string I'm working with. It is a single line string (therefore no need for special line endings) and everything seems to be escaped properly.

My application allows students to submit solutions for various exercises from computer science, the particular exercise here was to comment assembler code with the current register content. Therefore, the submitted solution contains a lot of special characters.

The solution can be loaded into a page in the application using AJAX, basically just a `jQuery('#elem').html()` call and its text is escaped using Rails' `escape_javascript` helper.

This works fine for every other solution, just not this one. I ran it through a JS validator (http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) which gives me the same error I get when running it directly, but I still don't know which part of the string is causing it.

---

The original text (with all control sequences, therefore in one line) is:

```
// Kommentierte Register mit Berechnungen, unten mit gegebenen Variaben.\r\n\r\nint dummy(int y, int* z)\r\n   {\r\n       asm (\r\n01         \"movl 0x8(%ebp), %ecx\\n“ \t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=? ; %ecx=y ; %edx=?\r\n02         \"movl 0xc(%ebp), %eax\\n\" \t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=z ; %ecx=y ; %edx=?\r\n03         \"movl (%eax), %edx\\n\"\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=z ; %ecx=y ; %edx=z\r\n04         \"xorl %eax, %eax\\n“ \t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=0 ; %ecx=y ; %edx=z\r\n05         \"addl %edx, %eax\\n\"\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=z ; %ecx=y ; %edx=z\r\n06         \"imull %ecx, %eax\\n\"\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=y*z ; %ecx=y ; %edx=z\r\n07         \"andl %eax, %edx\\n\"\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=y*z ; %ecx=y ; %edx=(y*z)&z\r\n08         \"leal (, %eax, 4), %eax\\n\"\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=4(y*z) ; %ecx=y ; %edx=(y*z)&z\r\n09         \"notl %eax\\n\"\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=~4(y*z) ; %ecx=y ; %edx=(y*z)&z\r\n10         \"andl $15, %eax\\n\"\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=~4(y*z)&15 ; %ecx=y ; %edx=(y*z)&z\r\n11         \"imull %eax, %edx\\n\"\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=~4(y*z)&15 ; %ecx=y ; %edx=((y*z)&z) * (~4(y*z)&15)\r\n12         \"movl 0xc(%ebp), %eax\\n\" \t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=z ; %ecx=y ; %edx=((y*z)&z) * (~4(y*z)&15)\r\n13         \"movl %edx,(%eax)\\n\"\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=*((y*z)&z) * (~4(y*z)&15) ; %ecx=y ; %edx=((y*z)&z) * (~4(y*z)&15)\r\n14         \"xorl %eax, %eax\\n\"\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t//%eax=0 ; %ecx=y ; %edx=((y*z)&z) * (~4(y*z)&15)\r\n\r\n       );\r\n   }\r\n   \r\n   int main()\r\n   {\r\n       int a = 10;\r\n       int temp = dummy(2, &a);\r\n       printf(\"Rueckgabe von dummy(2, &a) fuer a == 10: %d (Inhalt von eax)\\n\",\r\n              temp);\r\n       printf(\"Neuer Wert von a: %d\\n\", a);\r\n       return 0;\r\n   } \r\n\r\n\r\n//Mit Variablen:\r\n\r\n\r\n//y=2, *z= *a (=10)\r\n\r\nint dummy(int y, int* z)\r\n   {\r\n       asm (\r\n01         \"movl 0x8(%ebp), %ecx\\n“\t\t\t//%eax=? ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=?\r\n02         \"movl 0xc(%ebp), %eax\\n\" \t\t//%eax=0xA ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=?\r\n03         \"movl (%eax), %edx\\n\"\t\t\t//%eax=0xA ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=10\r\n04         \"xorl %eax, %eax\\n“ \t\t\t\t//%eax=0 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=10\r\n05         \"addl %edx, %eax\\n\"\t\t\t\t//%eax=10 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=10\r\n06         \"imull %ecx, %eax\\n\"\t\t\t\t//%eax=20 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=10\r\n07         \"andl %eax, %edx\\n\"\t\t\t\t//%eax=20 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n08         \"leal (, %eax, 4), %eax\\n\"\t\t//%eax=80 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n09         \"notl %eax\\n\"\t\t\t\t\t//%eax=47 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n10         \"andl $15, %eax\\n\"\t\t\t\t//%eax=15 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n11         \"imull %eax, %edx\\n\"\t\t\t\t//%eax=15 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n12         \"movl 0xc(%ebp), %eax\\n\" \t\t//%eax=0xA ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n13         \"movl %edx,(%eax)\\n\"\t\t\t\t//%eax=0xA ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(speicher Wert von %edx in Register 0xA)\r\n14         \"xorl %eax, %eax\\n\"\t\t\t\t//%eax=0 ; %ecx=2 ; %edx=0\r\n\r\n       );\r\n   }
```

---

The generated and escaped javascript code can be found in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stex/LHvR4/3/). It throws the same error in the browser's javascript console.

There are a few quotation marks in the string which do not seem to be escaped, but they are different ASCII chars (e.g. `0x8(%ebp), %ecx\n“` and should not be the problem.

What I tried so far was removing certain elements from the string (namely the forward slashes, the percentage symbols, the special quotation marks and even the normal quotation marks) before escaping it, but nothing has helped so far.

Am I just blind and missing something obvious or is there a secret javascript control sequence that causes this error?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

When I copy the response body from firebug (CTRL-C -> CTRL-V), post it into its console and run it directly, it works perfectly fine.

However, when I just right click onto the request and choose "Copy Response Body", I cannot run it without getting the error.

I ran it through a diff and got the following result: http://www.diffchecker.com/8y3eu2l5

There doesn't seem to be a visible difference, so which character is causing it?

**Edit 2:**

Just in case someone stumbles upon the same problem: The `escape_javascript` method in Rails does not seem to escape these characters automatically (at least not in the Rails version I'm using).

Using the solution pointed out [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2587) everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a strange character right before the text `\n\n\n//Mit Variablen` which causes the error. I'm not sure what character it is, but it makes the insertion fail.

Edit: it is a unicode line separation char (code 2028) as described [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm). Because it is not printed on most outputs, you can't spot it. In JSFiddle, it's visible, it's marked as a red dot.

Comment: Fun fact: your JS Validator does notice that odd character - if you double-click the "warning sign", it points the cursor directly that character - which, unfortunately, is not a visible character, but if you move align the line, you spot it anyway, because the cursor does not move.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I only have to find out what's causing the unicode newlines, my first guess would be that HAML is inserting them to [preserve](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_preservation) something, but I wasn't able to track it down yet.